# Is it possible to update or replace a cached entry's id with a new id in Apollo Client?

Tags: apollo-client, react-apollo

So I have a `station` in my app. Here's an example object:

```js
interface Station {
  id: number; // auto-increment
  stationId: number; // this is a constant
  name: string;
  status: 'live' | 'draft';
}
```

When updating the `station` the `stationId` will never change, but sql will auto increment the `id` field. The station's `status` will also be updated to `'draft'`. e.g.

```js
const previousStation: Station = {
  id: 1,
  stationId: 123456,
  name: 'Example splet right',
  status: 'live',
}

// ... then some sql-fu

const nextStation: Station = {
  id: 2,
  stationId: 123456,
  name: 'Example spelt right',
  status: 'draft',
}
```

Apollo client is unable to infer that `nextStation` should replace `previousStation`, so there are a lot of mutations that require readQuery/ readFragment.

I was hoping there may be a simpler solution, but the complexity arises from the `id` changing. If I could find all references to its object-id in the normalised data cache and update those fields. Is something like this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved. The key was to use a read/write fragment, using the old `object-id`, but passing in the new id as a reference. Then evict the old reference from the cache. It looked similar to this:

```js
mutation({
    variables,

    update(cache, { data }) {
        if (!data) {
            return;
        }

        const { id: newId, __typename } = data.station;

        const existing = cache.readQuery({
            query: GET_STATION_QUERY,
            variables: { id: variables.id }
        });

        if (existing) {
            const newStation = {
                ...(existing.getStation || {}),
                ...(data.updateStation || {})
            };

            cache.writeQuery({
                query: GET_STATION_QUERY,
                variables: { id: newId },
                data: { station: newStation }
            });
        }

        const oldObjectId = `${__typename}:${variables.id}`;

        const fragment = gql`
            fragment MyFragment on SomeType {
                station {
                    id
                }
            }
        `;

        const existingStationOnMyType = cache.readFragment({
            id: oldObjectId,
            fragment
        });

        if (existingStationOnMyType) {
            cache.writeFragment({
                id: oldObjectId,
                fragment,
                data: {
                    id: newId
                }
            });

            cache.evict({ id: oldObjectId });
            cache.gc();
        }
    }
});
```